# Tar of Linux Kernel corrupted error while untaring

Tags: linux, tar, linux-kernel, ubuntu-13.04

I have downloaded two versions of Linux kernel 3.9.9 and 3.10 from kernel.org.
When I am trying to untar this file I am getting this error

> Lzma library error: Corrupted input data

. I am not getting what is going wrong. I am sure that my downloaded file is not corrupted because I have downloaded this file for 3 times and in all 3 instances I get the same error. Can anyone suggest me what should I do to untar this file? I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Thank you.

Comment: What are the URLs and the commands you executed?

Comment: this is the link where from I downloaded the file https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.10.tar.xz

Comment: and for untaring I just used Archive Manager that comes pre-installed in Ubuntu

Comment: Works for me. Not on Ubuntu. Just using tar 'directly'.

Comment: `wget -O- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.10.tar.xz | tar -xJ`

Comment: Can you give me the SHA-512 of the file please?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and do this:

```
tar xvf linux-3.10.tar.xz
```

Comment: I tried out this earlier but it does not work. It gives following error: xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now